# Keep variable value while redirecting

Tags: asp.net

In my page (Page1.aspx), I have a function newButton_Click() which calls the Save function and redirects to the same page, because I've to load the page again.

```
protected void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  hdn_isMaintainance.Value = "true";
  btnSubmit_Click(sender, e);
  Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx?studid=" + oSession.StudentId);
}
```

In the function I'm changing **hdn_isMaintainance.Value = "true";** and I've to keep it "**true**" after redirecting.

In the Page_Load() function hdn_isMaintainance.Value is set using the below code:

```
if (Request.QueryString["isMaint"] != null && Request.QueryString["isMaint"] == "true")
{
  hdn_isMaintainance.Value = "true";
}
else
{
  hdn_isMaintainance.Value = "false";
}
```

Whats the best way? Should I keep it in session?

Comment: Session is the way to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in `query string` and after redirecting you can `get` it from query string

```
Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx?studid=" + oSession.StudentId+"&hdn_isMaintainance=true");
```

After redirecting you can get it from `query string` if query string `has value` than get it from query string otherwise set it to `default value`.